# Given 2 non-crossing polygons in 3D, both visible by a view ray Oz, determine which one is in front

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, 3d, render

I'm building a simple 3D model to draw cuboids in 3D. In this model there is **no** special cyclic case like A in front of B in front of C in front of A, or part of A is in front of B but part of B is in front of A.

Now given 2 polygons which are not crossing each other in 3D, both are visible (or partly visible) by the view direction is Oz. Determine which one is in front?
Apparently, I couldn't use minZ or maxZ. Here is a counter-example:
[image]

Comment: The magic google words are: Painter's Algorithm.  There's no awesome answer, but check https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/scanline/visibility/painter.htm

Comment: Your algorithm is not working because your view direction isn't the z-direction. But even then it could fail, e.g. `./` if you view this from above and move the dot slightly upwards and to the right, then it is hiding parts of the slash even though the slash is closest and furthest from the eye and the dot is in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

May be in your case that would be defined by:

> The plane that contains a given face defines two half spaces. The other face is in front if all four points of it are in the same half plane as that of the eye.

Be aware that there is no *simple*/*obvious* criterion, except if your model has very special/strong properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively simple where a solution exists: a cuboid (right rectangular prism) in projection is in front iff (if and only if) each of its visible faces appears as a complete parallelogram.

In your example above, the red cuboid is in front; two the the green faces are obscured (not parallelograms).